# The different output when I input for direct and text file in c

Tags: c

Following is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int a;
    scanf(" %d",&a);
    setbuf(stdin, 0);
    char *ch[a][10];

    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < a; i++){
        fgets(&ch[i], 10, stdin);
        printf("output: %s\n",ch[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I input :
2
G
GPA

Output is :
output: G
output: GPA

But I input same data from the text file, It output is:
output:
output: G

Like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoezN.png)

Why is this so?

Comment: Do you get any warnings from your compiler when you build the code? You should be and you should take heed of them. If not getting any then you should turn up compiler warnings.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `setbuf(stdin, 0);` line, don't use this to clear `stdin`.

Instead add a function like this to the code and call it after `scanf` to clear any characters left in `stdin`:

```
void clear_stdin(void){
    int c;
    while ((c=getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
}
```

Also this:

```
    char *ch[a][10];
```

Creates a matrix of pointers of dimension `a x 10` that point to `char` values. And it is not what you want, since you didn't make them point anywhere your compiler should be warning you that there is a problem.

You should use a normal matrix of `char` instead:

```
    char ch[a][10];
```

And there is no need to use & here:

```
    fgets(&ch[i], 10, stdin);
```

Since in this case `ch[i]` is a memory address already. So it should be:

```
    fgets(ch[i], 10, stdin);
```